# Will the compiler allocate any memory for code disabled by macro in C language?

Tags: c

For example:

```
int main()
{
   fun();//calling a fun
}

void fun(void)
{
    #if 0
    int a = 4;
    int b = 5;
    #endif
}
```

What is the size of the `fun()` function? And what is the total memory will be created for `main()` function?

Comment: The compiler will never even *see* those decls; the preprocessor will have stripped them long before that.

Comment: The function will be minimal; if you made it `static`, it would be eliminated altogether, but as it stands, it will be minimal.  Ditto for `main()`, except that under C99/C11/C18, it returns a 0 whereas `func()` returns no value.

Comment: Try to compile `#if 0 DONALD DUCK #endif` and that should answer the question :)

Answer (score 9):

Compilation of a C source file is done [in multiple phases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases). The phase where the preprocessor runs is done before the phase where the code is compiled.

The "compiler" will not even see code that the preprocessor has removed; from its point of view, the function is simply

```
void fun(void)
{
}
```

Now if the function will "create memory" depends on the compiler and its optimization. For a debug build the function will probably still exist and be called. For an optimized release build the compiler might not call or even keep (generate boilerplate code for) the function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, rephrased

Answer (score 1):

Compilation is split into 4 stages.

1. **Preprocessing**.
2. Compilation.
3. Assembler.
4. Linker

Compiler performs **preprocessor directives** before starting the actual compilation, and in this stage **conditional inclusions** are performed along with others.

The #if is a conditional inclusion directive.
From C11 draft 6.10.1-3:

> Preprocessing directives of the forms
>
> **#if** constant-expression new-line groupopt
>
> **#elif** constant-expression new-line groupopt
>
> check whether the controlling constant expression evaluates to nonzero.

As in your code #if 0 tries to evaluate to nonzero but remains false, thereby the code within the conditional block is excluded.

The preprocessing stage can be output to stdout with -E option:

> gcc -E filename.c

from the command above the output will give,

```
# 943 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4

# 2 "filename.c" 2
void fun(void)
{




}

int main()
{
  fun();
  return 0;
}
```

As we can see the statements with the #if condition are removed during the preprocessing stage.
This directive can be used to avoid compilation of certain code block.

Now to see if there is any memory allocated by the compiler for an empty function,

```
filename.c:
void fun(void)
{
}

int main()
{
  fun();
  return 0;
}
```

The size command gives,

```
$ size a.out
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1171        552       8    1731     6c3 a.out
```

and for the code,

```
filename.c:
void fun(void)
{
  #if 0
  int a = 4;
  int b = 5;
  #endif
}

int main()
{
  fun();
  return 0;
}
```

The output of size command for the above code is,

```
$ size a.out
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1171        552       8    1731     6c3 a.out
```

As seen in both cases memory allocated is same by which can conclude that the compiler does not allocate memory for the block of code disabled by macro.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Gcc reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html):

> The simplest sort of conditional is
>
> ```
> #ifdef MACRO
>
> controlled text
>
> #endif /* MACRO */
> ```
>
> This block is called a conditional group. controlled text will be
>   included in the output of the preprocessor if and only if **MACRO** is
>   defined. We say that the conditional succeeds if **MACRO** is defined,
>   fails if it is not.
>
> The controlled text inside of a conditional can include preprocessing
>   directives. They are executed only if the conditional succeeds. You
>   can nest conditional groups inside other conditional groups, but they
>   must be completely nested. In other words, `‘#endif’` always matches the
>   nearest `‘#ifdef’` (or `‘#ifndef’`, or `‘#if’`). Also, you cannot start a
>   conditional group in one file and end it in another.
>
> Even if a conditional fails, the controlled text inside it is still
>   run through initial transformations and tokenization. Therefore, it
>   must all be lexically valid C. Normally the only way this matters is
>   that all comments and string literals inside a failing conditional
>   group must still be properly ended.
>
> The comment following the `‘#endif’` is not required, but it is a good
>   practice if there is a lot of controlled text, because it helps people
>   match the `‘#endif’` to the corresponding `‘#ifdef’`. Older programs
>   sometimes put MACRO directly after the `‘#endif’` without enclosing it
>   in a comment. This is invalid code according to the C standard. CPP
>   accepts it with a warning. It never affects which ‘#ifndef’ the
>   ‘#endif’ matches.
>
> Sometimes you wish to use some code if a macro is not defined. You can
>   do this by writing `‘#ifndef’` instead of `‘#ifdef’`. One common use of
>   `‘#ifndef’` is to include code only the first time a header file is
>   included.